# python pandas dataframe change column data

Tags: python, lambda

**in my dataframe  ， data like this：**

```
['zhangfu': 0.74233128834355833, 'stock_code': '000001', 'zhenfu': 8.4215686274509807, 'stock_name': '平安银行 ']

['zhangfu': 0.642433128834355833, 'stock_code': '600000', 'zhenfu': 2.4315686274509807, 'stock_name': '浦发银行 ']
```

**and I want get data like this**

```
['zhangfu': 0.74, 'stock_code': '000001', 'zhenfu': 8.42, 'stock_name': '平安银行 ']

['zhangfu': 0.64, 'stock_code': '600000', 'zhenfu': 2.43, 'stock_name': '浦发银行 ']
```

**just want make cloumn 'zhangfu', 'zhenfu', left two point,
and I try to do**

```
df['zhangfu'] = df['zhangfu'].map(lambda x: round(x, 2))

df['zhenfu'] = df['zhenfu'].map(lambda x: round(x, 2))
```

**and get data like this:**

```
['zhangfu': 0.739999999999999999, 'stock_code': '000001', 'zhenfu': 8.4199999999999999, 'stock_name': '平安银行 ']

['zhangfu': 0.639999999999999999, 'stock_code': '600000', 'zhenfu': 2.429999999999999999, 'stock_name': '浦发银行 ']
```

**this is not I want ,then my question is why get that data, and what's the right method should I do ?**

Comment: try `df['zhangfu'] = pandas.Series([round(val, 2) for val in df['zhangfu'], index = df.index])`

Comment: @Meng: `df['zhangfu'] = df['zhangfu'].map(lambda x: "{0:.2f}".format(round(x,2)))`

Comment: @WoodChopper thanks, it works

Answer (score 0):

Set your printing options for `numpy` to:

```
numpy.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': '{: 0.2f}'.format})
```

This will display your floats with two decimals.